# Переадресация в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Не работает переадресация в Laravel.

Контроллер

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Botinkes;

class Controller2 extends Controller
{
    public function submit (Request $req)
    {

      $zayav=new Botinkes();
      $zayav->adr=$req->input('poisk');



      return redirect()->route('poisk1');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('poisk1');
    }
}
```

Форма

```html
<form action="/submit" method="post">
            @csrf
          <input type="text" id="poisk" name="poisk">
          <button type="submit">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` если роут будет прописан вот так:

```html
Route::get('/botinok', function () {
    return view('poisk1');

});
Route::post('/submit','Controller2@submit')->name('poisk1');
```

Спросил совета, посоветовали изменить роут на:

```html
Route::get('/botinok', function () {
    return view('poisk1');

})->name('poisk1');
Route::post('/submit','Controller2@submit');
```

Но в таком случае выдаёт уже вот эту ошибку `View [poisk1] not found.`

Comment: А что значит перевод последней ошибки на русский?

Answer (score 2):

Убедитесь что в resources/views у вас лежит файл poisk1.blade.php

так же если у вас уже имеется в контроллере метод индекс рекомендую переписать роут так

```
Route::get('/botinok','Controller2@index')->name('poisk1');

Route::post('/submit','Controller2@submit');
```

ну и валидация на прием запроса в метод submit (Controller2) вижу отсутствует, если некогда погружаться (хотя я бы рекомендовал) дополните его так:

```
public function submit (Request $req){
 $req->validate([       
 'poisk' => 'required|string', //пришедшие данные обязательны и должны быть строкой      
 ]);

 $zayav=new Botinkes();
 $zayav->adr=$req->poisk;


 return redirect()->route('poisk1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во втором варианте всё правильно, только, как пишет система нет view-a с именем "poisk1". Для проверки зайдите в папку resources->views и найдите файл с именем "poisk1.blade.php", если такого файла нет, то добавьте его и всё заработает! Если помог примите пож ответ!)))